# Filter numbers with alphabet pattern

Tags: regex, mongodb, algorithm, elasticsearch, search

I have been working on a application, objective of the application is to search for phone numbers with a specific pattern of numbers.

Search Scenario is beneath.

Let's say, if search pattern is:

```
*ABCABC
```

then result should be

```
91203156156
91203487487
```

if the search pattern is:

`*AABB`

then result should be:

```
91203851122
91203727733
```

My Question is

1. Is there any way to achieve this using Regex with MongoDB or
   Elastic search?
2. What would be the best practice to achieve this?
   Thanks.

Comment: In elasticsearch there is a lot of regex query , regexp query, wilcard query, prefix query, fuzzy query. Read the documentation first and then ask a specific question , please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can achieve this with grouping.
For instance, if you want to find patterns like `ABCABC`, you can search for `(.)(.)(.)\1\2\3`, broken down as follows:

```
(.)(.)(.)\1\2\3

(.)                Find any character and put it in the first group
   (.)             Find any character and put it in the second group
      (.)          Find any character and put it in the third group
         \1        Match the first group, ie the first character
           \2      Match the second group
             \3    Match the third group
```

Example, in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r".*(.)(.)(.)\1\2\3.*")
>>> regex.match("9120**3487487**")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match='9120**3487487**'>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, But the search scenario is not just limited to ABCABC. There are no limit to pattern possibilities. It can be \*ABCDEFG(where last 7 digit is continuous number), AB\*AB (first 2 and last 2 digit should be same) and so on.